# Serving NGINX Docker Container on NGINX Reverse Proxy how to redirect all routes to index.html

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a simple NGINX Docker container with a static site.
Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM nginx
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Now this container is being served by our reverse proxy whos config looks like this:

```
    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name domain.com;
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    
  #SSL stuff  
    
    
    server {
            listen 443;
            server_name domain.com;
    
            location / {
                    proxy_buffers           16 8K;
                    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_pass              IP:PORT of container;
                    try_files $uri $uri/  base.html;
            }
    }
```

I tried using try_files to redirect every route to the index.html which works but then for some reason whe i do /something/somthing
it doesnt work and css doesnt get loaded in.

I just need all requests to go to the index.html of the container

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new `location` block that serves static files, and in case if it fails, it will fallback to the named location `nodeapp`.

Note: SSL stuff should be inside the server block not outside.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name domain.com;

    # BTW, ssl stuff should be here

    location / {
        root /path/to/your/static/files;
        try_files $uri @nodeapp;
    }

    location @nodeapp {
        proxy_buffers           16 8K;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass              IP:PORT of container;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ill try this but is there any way to keep the files from the site on the separate server from the reverse proxy server

Comment: Yes, you just need to proxy to the separated static files server. So rather than using `try_files`, we use `proxy_pass` and we fallback 404 to @nodeapp but I don't recommend this way, a good practice is to make a new server block in the separated server for a sub domain, static.example.com which will be responsible of serving your static files.